# In Swift is there a way to directly set an existing UITableViewCell's reuseIdentifier?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I get my new cells by copying them from a master cell like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell?
    let cellId = String(format: "Cell%d", indexPath.row)
    cell = alertTable!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as! UITableViewCell?
    if cell == nil {
        let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(masterTableCell!)
        cell = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedData) as! UITableViewCell?
        cell!.reuseIdentifier = cellId   // compiler error: cannot assign to the result of this expression
    }
    populateAlertTableCell(cell!, alertIdx: indexPath.row)
    return cell!
}
```

But if you look carefully you see the problem.  I never reuse any cells because I'm not setting up the reuseIdentifer.  In fact what I really really need is a way to find the cell's row and I'm already using the tag for something else.  So if the reuseIdentifier worked then it could enable cell reuse and also be my way of identifying the cell's row.

Comment: Sorry, why are you trying to shove the row number into the reuse ID?

Comment: AFAIK when you create a cell it should have a unique reuse ID.  The row number is a good unique number for the cell.  Also I have need to obtain the row number from the UITableViewCell object for each cell.  I'd be able to use the reuse ID for that as well, if I could set it up that way.  Do you see a weakness with this strategy?

Comment: No, reuse IDs should be unique to a class of cell. Usually they're synonymous with a particular UITableViewCell subclass. The main purpose of the reuse ID is to save on view creation and deletion. The `forIndexPath:` mechanism and NIB/class registration by reuse ID stuff introduced in iOS 6 deals with when it's desirable to identify cells in the reuse collection by the position they once held.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve per-index path cell reuse, `UITableView` provides `func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. That will return the same instance of a cell as previously occupied a given index path if it is otherwise efficient to do so. There's no need to second-guess it.

Normal usage is previously to have used `func registerNib(_ nib: UINib?,
forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`, or to have designed the cell directly inside the Storyboard or NIB, and let the table view create instances of your cell class as required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understand your problem correctly.

First of you actually need to register a cell like so:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

This should be done when you set up your UITableView.

After that the call to

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
```

should give you the desired result.

Now to your specific code:

If `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called, you should not create a cell as you do, because that eliminates the whole point of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. The last mentioned method will either provide you with a reusable cell for the identifier you pass it or it will give you a new cell. This means you should not create a cell on your own.

For a better understanding, this is how you would basically do it in code (simplified) :

```
var tableView: UITableView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero)
    // instead of UITableViewCell you could also register you own cell (with another identifier)
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITablViewCell

    // set properties of you cell here
    // if you don't change the properties of your cell, it will still be reused,
    // meaning that a cell that just disappeard at the bottom will appear at the top unchanged        

    return cell
}
```